# missing title cause the website doesn't accept it

Tags: html, scalable

I want to have some content in a div which is scalable.

So that the user can scale the div as he wants.

Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: don't hate me for my title

Comment: can you please post your code till now? @crolex

Comment: i have no idea how to do this so i have no code. Maybe with css and javascript

Answer (score 2):

No one is going to just do it for you unless you show you have at least attempted the problem you are having. If you want a starting point though I recommend either using HTML5/CSS3 or Javascript for what you need. Both can get the job done